# Qt - layout doesn't shrink when a widget is removed

Tags: qt, qlayout

I'm working on a shape changing dialog.
It's supossed to enlarge when a More button is hit and shrink when is hit again. What I do is use `layout() -> addWidget()` and `layout() -> removeWidget()`. It enlarges properly when I add a widget but when I remove something it doesn't shrink. I tried using `layout() -> update()` and `layout() -> updateGeometry()`, but none of them worked.

EDIT**
Here's the functions I call when the buttons are clicked.

```
void findDialog::small()
{
    replaceBox -> hide();
    layout() -> removeWidget(replaceBox);
    moreButton -> show();
    updateGeometry();
}
void findDialog::extended()
{
    layout() -> addWidget(replaceBox);
    replaceBox -> show();
    moreButton -> hide();
    updateGeometry();
}
```

`replaceBox` is a `QGroupBox`

`moreButton` is a `QPushButton`

`findDialog` is a `QDialog inherited class`

Comment: Try calling `layout()->invalidate()` before updating - to remove cached info - that may help

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks

Comment: you mean QWidget::updateGeometry()? That should do the trick, if not please add more context (code snippets)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes I mean that function.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with `layout() -> setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);` So now the widget's size is always set to `sizeHint()`
That's why the layout wasn't updating as I wanted it to.
This way `updateGeometry()` is not needed.